# Set Variable Name in shell script permanently

Tags: bash, shell

I need to change variable name every time I ran script.
Lets say I have a variable

```
a="foo"
echo "Value is : $a"
```

and it will print

```
Value is foo
```

But in same script i am changing the variable value

```
a="bar"
```

And if i run the script again it should print

```
Value is bar
```

Can we achieve that in unix?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `$a="bar"` ought to give you an error message saying

```
bash: foo=bar: command not found
```

To set `a` to the string `bar`, use `a="bar"`. Notice that `$a` is the *value* of the variable `a`, and that `$a="bar"` is nonsensical.

If you want to change the value each time you run the script, you can do two things (at least).

1. Make `a` an environment variable.  This mean that you set `a` outside of the script and `export` it:

   ```
   export a="bar"
   ```

   Then you run your script as usual (it would need to be modified to not overwrite the value of `a` inherited from the environment first).  You could also use

   ```
   a="bar" ./myscript.sh
   ```

   to set the variable for the script only (i.e., not making it a variable in the calling shell).
2. Make the script take the value from the command line, so that you call the script like

   ```
   ./myscript.sh "bar"
   ```

   The script would then do

   ```
   a="$1"
   ```

   to set the value of `a` from the command line argument.  Here, `$1` means "the first command line argument".

Whichever way you go about doing this, you may also want to check that the value `"$a"` is *sane* (i.e. contains valid data) before using it.